# Access first element of an array without index

Tags: php, arrays

i have an xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <transaction dsxml_version="1.08">
    <action>action1</action>
    <action>action2</action>
    </transaction>
```

If i use simplexml i can access the first "action" with die following code

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_content);
    echo $xml->action; // Write "action1"
    echo $xml->action[0]; // Write "action1"
    echo $xml->action[1]; // Write "action2"
```

Now i create an array and a try to access it on the same way. But it doesent work.

We have a huge php skipt which use simple xml which contains a logical error. If i can emulate simple xml i can fix this error on one position

Comment: Clarify the problem please. You say "Now i create an array and a try to access it on the same way." Is this about SimpleXML or is it about arrays? Please show the code that doesnt work.

Comment: i want to build a class which can used instead of simple xml. but this class must contain the the functions. So $xml->action must return the first arrayelement.

Comment: no offense but why dont you just fix the error instead of coding around the error?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
current($xml->action);
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo array_shift(array_slice($xml->action, 0, 1));`

or if you're not worried about damaging the original array, `$xml->action` you can use the following

`echo array_shift($xml->action);`

Using array_shift will guarantee you get the first element if it's numbered or associative.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fake or mock object that simulates the behaviour you are looking for:

```
$action = new SimpleXMLArrayMock($action_array);

$xml->action = $action;

echo "\nFake:\n";
echo $xml->action, "\n";    // Write "action1"
echo $xml->action[0], "\n"; // Write "action1"
echo $xml->action[1], "\n"; // Write "action2"


/**
 * Mock SimpleXML array-like behavior
 */
class SimpleXMLArrayMock extends ArrayObject
{
    private $first;
    public function __construct(array $array)
    {
        $this->first = (string) $array[0];
        parent::__construct($array);
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->first;
    }

}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/IWygGbiT)

Answer (score 0):

use xpath so you can find the element

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
foreach($myarray as $key => $val)
{
    print $val;
    //if you don't need the rest of the elements:
    break;
}
```

**Added:**

You can even make it a function:

```
function get_first_element($myarray)
{
    foreach($myarray as $key => $val)
    {
        return $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes sure, but so i have to change my complete script. $xml->action is an array. And i want to access the first element if no index is given. Simple XML use this function, but i don't have any idea how they do it.

Comment: @user1001336 If you replace `$myarray` with `$xml->action` in my example above, wouldn't that solve your problem? I don't see how this makes you change your entire script?

Comment: @user1001336 Added function to make it easier implementing in your code.